# how to create a rake task for use with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake-task, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I am trying to implement the following rake task from the [CMS wiki](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Working-with-CMS-fixtures#using-fixtures-in-tests)

```
namespace :test do
  task :prepare do
    ENV['FROM'] = 'folder-name'
    ENV['TO']   = 'site-identifier'
    Rake::Task['comfortable_mexican_sofa:fixtures:import'].invoke
  end
end
```

I created test.rake with the above contents and put it in lib/tasks/

```
$ bundle exec rake:test
```

gives me: bundler: command not found: rake:test.
My search for documentation leads me to explainations of:  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.  I assume these are different things.  My question is:  How do I execute the above rake task?    Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your command is trying to run `rake:test`, which isn't a known command. You can see this by doing `which rake:test`.

I think you meant

```
bundle exec rake test
```

You can also do

```
bundle exec rake -T
```

To see the list of available tasks that have documentation.

For further reference on `bundle exec` see the [bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-exec.1.html).